# Fullcalendar Scheduler resourceRender

Tags: javascript, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-scheduler

How to get current view's name in resourceRender's callback function ?

I saw the doc official, I found this:

```
resourceRender: function(resourceObj, labelTds, bodyTds) {
  labelTds.css('background', 'blue');
}
```

From doc :

> The third argument holds the elements that visually contain the
>   resource’s events (jQuery object). The exact DOM node depends on the
>   type of the current view. Certain views might not support this
>   argument, and will provide an empty jQuery set.

Maybe we can find some information about current view from third argument `bodyTds` ?

Thanks for any suggestion.

Comment: I haven't tried but I'd expect you can run https://fullcalendar.io/docs/getView within that function and get the view type that way.

Comment: @ADyson, that way works, Thank you for you answer correct.

Answer (score 0):

This has since changed in version Full Calendar Resource Timeline Schedular version 4.0. I used an 'addEventListener' to the object 'view' See the below snippet calling 'resourceRender' so you can see how to access this during render.  Hope that helps :}

REF: https://fullcalendar.io/docs/view-object

```
document.addEventListener('DOMContentLoaded', function () {
    var calendarEl = document.getElementById('calendar');
    var calendar = new FullCalendar.Calendar(calendarEl, {
        schedulerLicenseKey: '<hidden>',
        plugins: ['interaction', 'resourceTimeline'],
        resourceLabelText: 'Resources',
        resources: "<see fullcalendar support docs>",
        events: "<see fullcalendar support docs>",
        resourceRender: function (renderInfo) {
            renderInfo.el.addEventListener("click", function () { console.log('clicked:' + renderInfo.view.title+ ' ' + renderInfo.view.type); });
        }
    });
    calendar.render();
});
```